# Facebook plugin or widget for friends selection without application request

Tags: facebook, api

Is there a facebook friend selector widget or plugin that shows the UI for all the friends of the user, in which the user then selects one or more friends. After that facebook gives me list of ids of selected friends ?

fb:multi-friend-selector only works within the context of sending application request as for as I know, so this would not work for me because I do not want to send application request but just needs list of ids of selected friends. This plugin or widget must work from my website after user has logged in via facebook connect and not from within facebook canvas application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for does not exist as a plugin or widget provided by facebook. However, you can very easily build one yourself. Using the javascript SDK you can request the list of the users friends using the Graph API. After that just build the widget you are looking for with normal html and javascript. To make the request to get all a users friends do the following:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
  // do something with the result
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. If there is no such thing, then i will have to do it myself but its a lot of work to get the same functionality such as start typing a name, it automatically pulls out friends starting with the typed letters, pagination if there are lot of friends etc etc.

Comment: Yeah, it is unfortunate, but the FBML elements are really only for very specialized cases. Also, it is important to remember that Facebook is phasing out FBML so in the long run doing it yourself is probably better. Also, be sure to mark this as the answer.

Comment: sorry did not know about answer marking on stackoverflow. Just did that.